# ExpandableListView using SimpleCursorTreeAdapter

Tags: android

I am creating ExpandableListView using SimpleCursorTreeAdapter. I am facing lot of problems.

Can anyone tell me how I can I do this?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this example on the android docs for [SimpleCursorTreeAdapter here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.html) check it out.